# Efficiently using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using pandas and np.where to fill a new column if multiple conditions are met.

For this I am using the following database (but then 100 times bigger).

[image]

What I am doing now is:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == 2018) & (df['price'] > 30000) & (df['fuel description'] == Petrol), 12, 10)
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == 2019) & (df['price'] > 30000) & (df['fuel description'] == Petrol), 15, 10)
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == 2020) & (df['price'] > 30000) & (df['fuel description'] == Petrol), 18, 10)
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == 2021) & (df['price'] > 30000) & (df['fuel description'] == Petrol), 21, 10)
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == 2022) & (df['price'] > 30000) & (df['fuel description'] == Petrol), 24, 10)
```

As you can see I am only changing the condition for the column: "year".

I am looking for an efficient way to use the other two conditions (price and fuel description) because I am just copying them now.

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```py
condition = (df['year'] >= 2018) & (df['year'] <= 2022) & (df['price'] > 30000) \
            & (df['fuel description'] == Petrol)
df['new_column'] = np.where(condition, 12 + (df['year']-2018)*3, 10)
```

**Update**:

If there is no correlation between the values to be filled, you can construct an array in advance. The conditions are still only evaluated once.

Example:

```
year_to_value = {2018: 12, 2019: 15, 2020: 18, 2021: 21, 2022: 24}
values = df['year'].map(year_to_value)
df['new_column'] = np.where(condition, values, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks! The 12,15,18,21,24 is just random.... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Tim, it doesn't matter. You can pack them into an array in advance. Anyway, you only need to write these conditions once.

Comment: Cool! I am going to use this. One more question, how you would do it if there is another variable condition besides year. So for example the result is only 12 if the price is below 30000 and year 2018. The result is only 15 if the price is below 40000 and year 2019 etc.

Comment: It's similar, but you may need to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply).

Comment: Hmm sorry this is above my python knowledge.. I learned a lot yesterday about the separate functions but how to combine them with apply so I can add a third variable condition, no clue...

Comment: @Tim, you need to define a filter function on a row and then pass it to `apply`. In this way, you will iterator each row, perform some condition checks, and set the proper value. You don't need `np.where` anymore.

Comment: @Tim, but don't be bothered by my advice, maybe I misunderstand your requirements. Feel free to open a new post for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap your duplicate code into a function to avoid repeating yourself, something like this:

```
def get_year_condition(df, year):
    return df['year'] == year & df['price'] > 30000 & df['fuel description'] == 'Petrol'
```

And then use like this:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(get_year_condition(df, 2021), 21, 10)
df['new_column'] = np.where(get_year_condition(df, 2022), 24, 10)
...
```